# Typescript: Array of Objects of another Array (Angular6)

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object

I have this array of "food":

```
"food": [
 { 
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Kabeljaufilet",
    "preis": 3.55,
    "art": "mit Fisch"
},
{
  "id": 12,
  "name": "Spaghetti Bolognese",
  "preis": 3.85,
  "art": "mit Fleisch"
},
{
  "id": 13,
  "name": "Pizza Salami",
  "preis": 3.99,
  "art": "mit Fleisch"
},
```

Now I need another Array called "foodplan", where I can add, delete *etc.* foods from the first array.

I have never created Arrays where Objects of another Arrays were implemented. How to go on now?

**Foodplan** needs the Attributes: **FoodPerWeek**, where 5 food objects are in and WeekNumber Foodplan needs methods to showFood, addFood, changeFood and deleteFood.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the food objects are held in another array, your `foodplan` should just be an array, exactly like the `food` one you've got there

Comment: @user184994 and what methods can I use, to get specific objects from the food array? - The problem here is, that I need 5 different foodplans (by adding weeknumber) for 5 weeks, how can I handle this?

Comment: It depends what you want to do really. You can get one out using it's index for example, using `this.food[0]` would get the first one, or you can use the `find` function to get one, like `this.food.find((f) => f.id === 12)` would return the one with id 12

Comment: **Foodplan** needs the Attributes: **FoodPerWeek**, where 5 food objects are in and *WeekNumber*

Foodplan needs methods to showFood, addFood, changeFood and deleteFood.

Comment: So you can use `push` to add an item to an array. `this.foodPlan.foodPerWeek.push(this.food[0])` would push a copy of the first item in `food`, and place it in `foodPerWeek`

Answer (score 2):

This is just a basic example. 
Of course you could dynamically resize the array if you prefer. 
There need to be some checks to validate the input, etc. I leave this to you. Have fun.

```
enum WeekDay {
  Monday = 0,
  Tuesday = 1,
  Wednesday = 2,
  Thursday = 3,
  Friday = 4
}

class Food {
  public id: number
  public name: string
  public preis: number
  public art: string
}

class FoodPlan {
  private weeklyFood: Food[] = new Array<>(5)

  addFood(food: Food, weekDay: WeekDay) {
    this.weeklyFood[weekDay] = food
  }

  showFood(weekDay: WeekDay) {
    console.log(this.weeklyFood[weekDay])
  }

  remove(weekDay: WeekDay) {
    this.weeklyFood[weekDay] = null
  }
}
let foodPlan: FoodPlan = new FoodPlan()
let firstFood: Food = new Food()

firstFood.id = 1
firstFood.name = "Kabeljaufilet"
firstFood.preis = 3.55
firstFood.art = "mit Fisch"

foodPlan.addFood(firstFood, WeekDay.Wednesday)
foodPlan.showFood(WeekDay.Wednesday)
foodPlan.remove(WeekDay.Wednesday)
```

Comment: hey. thanks first, will it be possible to add functions with your solution like add/delete/change  **foodplans** ?

Comment: uff. I'm having a hard time, implementing your code in Angular6/Typescript... the structure just needs to be different.

Comment: I can't do your homework, I'm sorry. You will have to try by yourself.